# C++ delete statement isn't doing what I think it should -- returns an error

Tags: c++

I am looking at the following code segment.  It compiles well, but returns an error when the delete statement is included. The error is that the pointer being freed was not allocated.  What have I missed here?  My searches of the stack overflow site have not turned up a question that exactly duplicates this question.  The link that points to a "duplicate" does not look like a duplicate to me.

The code is...

```
long val2 = 72;
long *pval2 = NULL;
pval2 = new long;
pval2 = &val2;
std::cout << "pval2 = " << *pval2 << "\n";  //prints the correct value
delete pval2;
```

The compiler I am using for this is project the c++ compiler that is in the Xcode development tool.

Thank you

Comment: Since `val2` was not allocated by `new`, its address, `&val2` cannot be passed to `delete`.

Comment: You can't free unallocate address.

Comment: Read some good book on C++ programming. Read about [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_memory_management) and [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and [pointer aliasing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing); use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pval2 = new long;` allocates a long and stores the address of it in `pval2`.

`pval2 = &val2;` then overwrites that address with a different one, that being the location of `val2`. At this point you've lost the address of that allocated long.

Consequently, when you finally get down to `delete pval2;` it tries to deallocate something which you never allocated with new in the first place and thus causes problems.

Answer (score 3):

```
pval2 = new long;
```

This gives you some memory space to play with.

```
pval2 = &val2;
```

This then immediately throws that memory space away and makes the pointer point to the location of `val2` (which is not `free`able memory).  If you meant to copy the *value* of val2 into the new memory address, then you need to dereference the pointer:

```
*pval2 = val2;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only give to delete a memory address returned by new. &val2 is an address on the stack and send it to delete is an error.

Last, once you overwrite pval2 with &val2, you lost the previous memory address allocated on the heap, so it is a memory leak…

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to delete something on the stack

this line `pval2 = &val2;` is pointing to something on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

after the allocation pval2 points to somewhere in the heap. then you override this point to somewhere in the stack. now you got someplace on the heap which you cannot access - that's your mistake

Comment: After the helpful comments shown above, my working code is as follows: